# How to set -level values via Imagemagick GUI prompt?

Tags: linux, shell-script, imagemagick

How to set required -level values via ImageMagick GUI dialog prompt?
For example, I want set values `-level 10%,90%` from Imagemagick GUI prompt.
It's not clear, what values in GUI dialog correspond to this CLI values?

[image]